# Exporting the Print output in a file

Tags: export

I have the following list

```
FirstPart={pr[4, k1, 0] == 1/pr1, pr[4, k2, 0] == 1/pr2, pr[4, k3, 0] == 1/pr3, 
 pr[4, k1 - k2, mZ] == 1/pr4, pr[4, k2 - k3, 0] == 1/pr5, 
 pr[4, k1 - k3, 0] == 1/pr6, pr[4, k1 - p1, 0] == 1/pr7, 
 pr[4, k1 - p1 - p2, 0] == 1/pr8, pr[4, k2 - p1 - p2, 0] == 1/pr9, 
 pr[4, k3 - p1 - p2, 0] == 1/pr10, pr[4, k2 - p1, 0] == 1/pr11, 
 pr[4, k3 - p1, 0] == 1/pr12}
```

and want to export in in a file as

[image]

This can be printed very well as

```
Do[
  Print["id ", FirstPart[[kk, 1]], "=", FirstPart[[kk, 2]], ";"];
  , {kk, 1, Length[FirstPart]}];
```

But my question is can I save the print output in a txt file?

Comment: what is `FirstPart` ? is this the name of your list?

Comment: yes sorry for not mentioning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
lis = {pr[4, k1, 0] == 1/pr1, pr[4, k2, 0] == 1/pr2, 
   pr[4, k3, 0] == 1/pr3, pr[4, k1 - k2, mZ] == 1/pr4, 
   pr[4, k2 - k3, 0] == 1/pr5, pr[4, k1 - k3, 0] == 1/pr6, 
   pr[4, k1 - p1, 0] == 1/pr7, pr[4, k1 - p1 - p2, 0] == 1/pr8, 
   pr[4, k2 - p1 - p2, 0] == 1/pr9, pr[4, k3 - p1 - p2, 0] == 1/pr10, 
   pr[4, k2 - p1, 0] == 1/pr11, pr[4, k3 - p1, 0] == 1/pr12};

data = First@Last@Reap[Do[Sow[{"id ", lis[[kk, 1]], "=", lis[[kk, 2]], ";"}], 
           {kk, 1, Length[lis]}]]

Export["test.txt", data, "Table"]
```

And this gives this file

[image]